# Flutter StatefulWidget rebuild infinity times

Tags: flutter, dart

The issue is that the whole widget is rebuilds itself infinite times.

I had try convert it to `StatelessWidget`, but nothing changed.

But when I copy the same code to another class its works fine.

Here is my code.

```
class _SignalpageState extends State<Signalpage> {
  Future getData2() async {
    var signaldata = {"chanelid": '1'};
    var url = 'http:....';
    var response = await http.post(url, body: signaldata);
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    data = responsebody;
    print(data);
    return data;
  }


  Future getData1() async {
    var url = "http:......php";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    datarates = responsebody;

    return datarates;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(" Signals"),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            top: true,
            maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
            bottom: true,
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: OLs,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                initialData: [getData1(), getData2()],
                future: Future.wait([getData2(), getData1()]),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Comment: Are you sure that using getData1 getData2 as your initialData is safe? Does you code work as excepted when you remove it?

Comment: The `initialData` parameter of the `FutureBuilder` widget is used to supply data to your `builder` function while the `Future` you provide to the `future` parameter is still waiting.

So, you cannot pass `[getData1(), getData2()]` into `initialData` since that will return `[Future, Future]` which is not what you intended.

Also, one of your futures is a `get` and another is a `post`. So I am pretty sure, that is not intended.

Explain your usecase further.

Comment: yeah you should remove initial data from future builder as the data itself is future so its of no use.

Comment: you mean remove this    initialData: [getData1(), getData2()], and convert the other function into post?

Comment: remove it and nothing change!!!!

Comment: @Gaspard Merten yes i have try it and nothing change

Comment: post your complete code..there may be something else which causing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't have to re-instantiate the Future every time** you instantiate the `FutureBuilder`, but you have to keep it in a field of your State class. Otherwise when the future completes and rebuilds the FutureBuilder, the FutureBuilder will receive as an argument a new future which has yet to complete, and so on in an infinite loop.

For a more detailed explanation see for example the article https://flutterigniter.com/future-async-called-multiple-times/

Comment: thats work but one question. I have a print here[code] '  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print("ok");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar('
still printing infinity times is this mean that the StatelessWidget is still rebuilding infinity times?